# Making too many transparent views makes complicated in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Before Starting I want to make sure one thing whether we can make the `ViewController` transparent (alpha), as far my knowledge it is NO.

I have a `ViewController` which consists of 8 `UIButton` objects over it. Whenever I press `Button1`, `Button2` I am loading a `ViewController`. Since the `ViewController` cannot be made transparent, I just moved that `View` to my `HomeViewController.xib` and I am loading the `view` using `-addSubView:`. And I am changing the alpha value to make it as transparent.

But the thing is in `Button1` View and `Button2` View, in both views I am having table view.  When I bring everything to the same `HomeViewController` class , I am having too much of code in a single class.

Is there any way to do this?? Adding many Views in the same `ViewController` not a problem, but it increases the code too. Which looks ugly. Please help me out.

If I have confused about my question here I am giving a short description of what I would like to do
Whenever I press a `Button` in `ViewController`, I want to load a `View`/`ViewController` Transparently.

Comment: UIViewControllers have nothing to do with transparency, that is the job of their UIView.  You need to keep the View Controller and the View separate in your mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Before Starting I want to make sure one thing whether we can make the
>   ViewController transparent (alpha), as far my knowledge it is NO.

You can't adjust a view controllers alpha directly. You can adjust a view controllers view properties alpha, ex: `myViewController.view.alpha`, and you can do this for any view that you want except for your root view (the bottom of the view stack). Lowering your root views alpha would allow the user to see the springboard through your app.

> But the thing is , In Button1 View and Button2 View , in both views I
>   am having table view. When I bring everything to the same
>   HomeViewController class , I am having too much of code in a single
>   class.
>   Is there any way to do this ?? Adding Many Views in the same
>   ViewController not a problem, but it increases the code too. Which
>   looks ugly. Please help me out.

I'm not sure I understand the problem here. As long as you format your code correctly and keep well organized this isn't a problem. I personally have used view controllers in excess of 15k lines of code and never had a problem, and I'm sure there are developers that have used way more.

> If I have confused about my question here I am giving a short
>   description of what I would like to do Whenever I press a Button in
>   ViewController , I want to load a View/ViewController Transparently.

Continue the way you have been describing. (adding alpha adjusted `UIView`'s as subviews) There is nothing wrong with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the Wonderful description. I felt is there will be any other logic to do it. But it seems NO. All I have to do is , move all the viewcontroller code to the HomScreenViewController class and want to add many views as much as possible.

Comment: And I have one more doubt too , After moving all the views to the same class. If I give the self.view.alpha = 0.3 , then it is affecting its subview too, am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: @Perseus You aren't doing anything wrong, this is standard view stack behavior. There is a way to make a super views transparency not effect its subviews, but I can't seem to remember it right now. A quick Google search should show you everything you need to know.